# Webpack - access loaderContext in loader options

Tags: javascript, webpack

I would like to use the webpack loader API when defining the loader configuration.

webpack.options.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            loader: 'loader-name',
            options: {
                // I need to have access to the loader context here
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I was hoping that I can use `options: function () { ... }`, but this throws `Invalid configuration object` warning.

Is there any chance to make this work?